# LUIS, change the culture and change also some function

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I'm learning Microsoft LUIS but I found a strange fedback using app in different cultures.
I'm italian so my app should have it-it as the culture but I saw that there are almost two things that are different from an app with culture en-us and one with culture it-it:
1) I can't use prebuild domains on italian app;
2) the entity "DateTimeV2" is not present and the first version of this entity don't seem work as well as DateTimeV2 used on the other app.
Could someone tell me if these difference could be caused because I have a free account?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment [DateTimeV2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-datetimev2) is available for LUIS model based on model language. This limitation has no relation to paid or trial subscription and it is defined in this overview: [Entities per culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-reference-prebuilt-entities)

You might contribute to [MS Recognizers-Text](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text) GitHub project to have all entities in Italian too.

---

The [prebuilt domains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-domains#communication) are slightly different concept. You can create "own domain" as one of your LUIS applications. Once you are satisfied you may export the application definition to json [image]

and then import this definition under new name when needed.

Comment: Do you know if there is ome thing like the recognizer project also for the prebuild domains?